# Drop down list issue 

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Html**

```
   <a id="btn" class="btn" href="#."></a>
   <div id="main-dropdown" class="hide">
       <ul id="dropdown">
          <li><a href="/">Back </a></li>
          <li><a href="/foo">Foo </a></li>
          <li><a href="/bar">Bar </a></li>
          <li><a href="/baz">Baz </a></li>
          <li><a href="/no">No Bar </a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main-dropdown").removeClass('hide');
    $("#main-dropdown").addClass('show');
    return false;
});

$("#dropdown").mouseup(function() {
    return false
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if($('#main-dropdown').hasClass('show')) {
        $("#main-dropdown").removeClass('show');
        $("#main-dropdown").addClass('hide');
        return false;
    }
    $("#main-dropdown").removeClass("show");
    $("#main-dropdown").addClass("hide");
});
```

Problem:
When I click on the href (id = btn) a drop down comes but when I again click on that button is should hide 
which is not happening. Where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$("#dropdown").mouseup(function() {
    return false
});
```

to

```
$("#dropdown a").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

some more notes

1. remove the `return false;` from the `mouseup` events because there is no default action for that event..
2. no need to call both `e.preventDefault();` and `return false` for links.. one should be enough. (if you want to stop the bubbling then use only `return false`
3. check out the [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

simplified version

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#main-dropdown').hasClass('hide')){
        $("#main-dropdown").toggleClass('hide show');
    }
});

$("#dropdown a").click(function() {
    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
      if($('#main-dropdown').hasClass('show')) {
        $("#main-dropdown").toggleClass('hide show');
    }
});
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yjWNg/1/

---

**update for comment**

There was a small error in the fact that we should handle the click event in all cases..

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#main-dropdown").toggleClass('show hide');
});

$("#dropdown a").click(function() {
    return false;
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
      if($('#main-dropdown').hasClass('show')) {
        $("#main-dropdown").toggleClass('hide show');
    }
});
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yjWNg/5/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but my problem still exit. In your example once I click the show link it should open but if the drop down is visible it should get hide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to do but give a try to this : http://jsbin.com/ehola3/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#main-dropdown").hasClass('hide')){
        $("#main-dropdown").removeClass('hide');
        $("#main-dropdown").addClass('show');
    }
    else{
        $("#main-dropdown").removeClass('show');
        $("#main-dropdown").addClass('hide');
    }
    return false;
 });
```

something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using toggle() to show and hide content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle</button>
<p style="display: none">Hello</p>
<script>

$("button").click(function () {
  $("p").toggle("show");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle that `hide`class

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main-dropdown").toggleClass('hide');
});
```

#### Working Example:  [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/c5TDK/)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Show/Hide</a>
<div id="main-dropdown" class="hide">
    <ul id="dropdown">
      <li><a href="/">Back </a></li>
      <li><a href="/foo">Foo </a></li>
      <li><a href="/bar">Bar </a></li>
      <li><a href="/baz">Baz </a></li>
      <li><a href="/no">No Bar </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main-dropdown").toggleClass('hide');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {display: none;}
```